# $T^2$-statistic for transformed data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, t-test, data-transformation

I was faced with such an exercise in the textbook:
Consider the $T^2$-statistic $N(\bar {\mathbf x} -\mu_0)'S^{-1}_X(\bar {\mathbf x} -\mu_0)$ for $H_0: E[X]=\mu_0$ based on a sample of size N with sample mean vector $\bar {\mathbf x}$ and covariance matrix $S_X$. Suppose that the data are transformed according to $\mathbf {Y =AX +b}$, where $A$ is a nonsingular $p \times 
 p$ matrix and $\mathbf b \in \Bbb R^p$. Show that the  $T^2$-statistic for  $H^*_0: E[\mathbf Y]=\mathbf { A\mu_0+b} $ based on $\bar {\mathbf y}$ and $S_Y$ is identical to $N(\bar {\mathbf x} -\mu_0)'S^{-1}_X(\bar {\mathbf x} -\mu_0)$.
And I'm stuck. I think here I can try to find the Mahalanobis distance.
It is known that this distance is invariant under affine transformation. But I'm not sure about this approach. I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: This is phrased as homework, so please add the `self-study` tag and share your thoughts.

Comment: First try to express $(\bar y - \mathbb{E}[Y])$ in function of $A$, $\bar x$, $\mu_0$, then express $S_Y$  in function of $S_X$ and $A$, and then it sould nicely simplify. Don't hesitate to post what you tried.

Comment: @Pohoua $(\bar {\mathbf y} -E[Y])= \mathbf A\bar {\mathbf x}+\mathbf b - \mathbf AE[X]-\mathbf b = \mathbf A\bar {\mathbf x} - \mathbf A\mu_0 = \mathbf A(\bar {\mathbf x} - \mu_0)$

Comment: @Helen Yes, this is correct. Now you need the covariance matrix of $Y$.

Comment: @Pohoua $S_Y = E[(\bar {\mathbf y} -E[Y])(\bar {\mathbf y} -E[Y])^T] =E[\mathbf A(\bar {\mathbf x} - \mu_0)(\bar {\mathbf x} - \mu_0)^T \mathbf A^T]= \mathbf A E[(\bar {\mathbf x} - \mu_0)(\bar {\mathbf x} - \mu_0)^T]\mathbf A^T = AS_XA^T $

Comment: @Helen. Yes, so now you can compute the $T^2$ statistic of $Y$. Be carefull with matrix inversion and transposition (order of multiplication is changes).

Comment: @Pohoua Yes, I wrote that statistics down and got it equal to the statistics for $X$. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. You did prove that Mahalanobis distance is invariant under affine transformation.